# Docker machine connection with https

Tags: docker, maven

I am new to Docker. I installed Docker tool box on my Windows machine.

Using pom.xml I want to generate docker image .
pom.xml:-

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.11</version>
    <configuration>
        <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
        <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
        <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/docker</dockerDirectory>
        <dockerHost>https://192.168.99.102:2376</dockerHost>
        <dockerCertPath>C:/Users/shridhar/.docker/machine/machines/default</dockerCertPath>
        <forceTags>true</forceTags>
        <imageTags>
            <imageTag>${projectVersion}</imageTag>
            <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
        </imageTags>

        <!-- push the image on docker hub -->
        <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
        <registryUrl>https://hub.docker.com</registryUrl>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <!-- war file locaion wheere war should be present (copied) -->
                <targetPath>/   </targetPath>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <include>${project.build.finalName}.war</include>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Docker machine details

```bash
$ env | grep 'DOCKER'
```

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.102:2376
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\shridhar\.docker\machine\machines\default
```

I get the below exception:

```
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
```

If I make tcp connection

```xml
<dockerHost>tcp://192.168.99.102:2376</dockerHost>
```

then I get below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An HTTPS URI for DOCKER_HOST must be provided to use Docker client certificates
```

What changes do I have to make to build image sucessfully?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you say you want to build an image (and not push it to Docker hub or wherever):

[docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) project recommends using [dockerfile-maven](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) for new projects, as the former

> [...] ultimately led to a lot of unnecessary confusion with our users that stemmed from introducing extra abstractions and a need for configuration on top of what Docker is providing.

The dockerfile-maven `README` should get you started, with both a sample `Dockerfile` and  the relevant `plugin` section for your `pom.xml`